# Using Reflection to access an array from a ScriptableObject in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, code-reflection

I am trying to get access to a set of stored variables inside a scriptible object in Unity. This class (SectorDeclaration) has a method to pull a variable with a string of the variables name from it:

```
public Weightings[] GetVariName(string variableName)
{
    Type this_class = Type.GetType("SectorDeclaration");
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldtype = this_class.GetField(variableName);
    Weightings[] fieldFind = (Weightings[])fieldtype.GetValue(null);
    return (Weightings[])fieldFind;
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

`TargetException: Non-static field requires a target
System.Reflection.MonoField.GetValue (System.Object obj) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoField.cs:108)
SectorDeclaration.GetVariName (System.String variableName) (at Assets/Code/Gameplay Element/level Elements/SectorDeclaration.cs:54)
BaseGameManager.InitializeNPCSystem () (at Assets/Code/Managers/BaseGameManager.cs:87)
BaseGameManager.Start () (at Assets/Code/Managers/BaseGameManager.cs:73)`

It works until the code reaches `Weighting[] fieldFind = (Weighting[])Fieldtype.GetValue(null);` I've used this code in another area but it is not working here, I've tried with `System.object obj` but it comes up with namespace doesn't contain this type, as well as with the type I am trying to access. Honestly, not sure what's wrong. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: What's the difference between the code that is working somewhere else and the code that is not working?  That might be a hint as to why it's not working here.

Comment: that code is in a static class, so I know the null works there.

Comment: Please keep in mind that reflection is a language feature which is best avoided. There are very few edge-cases where you *must* use reflection. Most of the time it can be avoided by using the right data structures and object-oriented patterns. In this case you seem to want to access some key/value data store. When that is the case, store your values in a [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error identifies exactly what the problem is:

> TargetException: Non-static field requires a target
>   System.Reflection.MonoField.GetValue (System.Object obj)

Since the field isn't `static`, that means the values of the field are stored on an *instance* of the type. So when you ask the `FieldInfo` to fetch the values for you, you need to tell it *from which instance* you want it to fetch them. (You might have a dozen `SectorDeclaration` instances in your game, and it doesn't know one from the other).

The way to give it a target from which to fetch values is the `obj` argument. [As shown in the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_FieldInfo_GetValue_System_Object_), you set that to `null` *only when the field you want to read is `static`*. Otherwise, it should be set to the instance you want to read from.

Assuming this method is inside the `SectorDeclaration` type, and you want the values from `this` instance, you can pass `this` as the argument:

```
Weightings[] fieldFind = (Weightings[])fieldtype.GetValue(this);
```

---

Of course, in the case where we already know what type we're fetching these values from, and it's one under our control, we could bypass the use of reflection entirely in a couple of different ways.

For instance, we could use a `switch` statement, using an `enum` to identify the different fields we might want to use (which avoids ["stringly-typed" code](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped), though you can use [Enum.Parse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) if your source absolutely must use strings):

```
public class SectorDeclaration : ScriptableObject {

    // I have no idea what these weights represent, so I'm spitballing here...
    public enum WeightingCategory {
        LoadPriorityWeights,
        SpawnProbabilityWeights,
        BiomeDistributionWeights
    }

    public Weightings[] loadPriorities;
    public Weightings[] spawnProbabilities;
    public Weightings[] biomeDistribution;

    public Weightings[] GetWeightingsByCategory(WeightingCategory category) {
        switch(category) {
            case WeightingCategory.LoadPriorityWeights: return loadPriorities;
            case WeightingCategory.SpawnProbabilityWeights: return spawnProbabilities;
            case WeightingCategory.BiomeDistributionWeights: return biomeDistribution;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public Weightings[] GetWeightingsByCategory(string categoryName) {
        return GetWeightingsByCategory((WeightingCategory)System.Enum.Parse(WeightingCategory, categoryName));
    }
}
```

This will likely be substantially faster at runtime and less bug-prone than using reflection.

Comment: Amazing, I was reading through the documentation and couldn't fully comprehend it, so thanks for clearing that up, stupid really considering I've built a state machine. as for the suggestion this class is going to be polymorphic so its going to be easier to use this string identifier down the line thanks for the fix, and I'll reply with my results. Your other suggestion is much appreciated. Thank-you so much, such a stupid misunderstanding.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet we can come up with a non-reflection solution to your polymorphism case too, if we learn a bit more about what problem this class hierarchy is solving. ;)

Comment: thanks but I can't disclose that :/. luckily this runs only once 9 times at level start, so runspeed doesnt matter as much, thanks for the help though. Plus I'm pulling different classes instead of just weightings and i know how to sort that part lol.